# Fill a column with a sequence int numbers in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have to alter my table adding a column that I have to fill with sequence of int numbers. Does anyone knows how can I fill this column?
I tried this:

```
set @i = 1;
Update db.table set new_column=(@i := @i+1) where id>0;
```

But this just fill all lines with the number 2. =(

Answer (score 2):

you can easy do so:

```
UPDATE db.table 
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @myid := 0) AS parameter
SET new_column = @myid := (@myid +1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Update your_table
join
(
   select id, @i := @i+1 as rank
   from your_table
   cross join (select @i := 0) ia
   where id > 0
   order by id
) tmp on tmp.id = your_table.id
set your_table.new_column = tmp.rank
```

Answer (score 0):

All this answers works for me. And I did another one

```
delimiter #
create procedure fill_column()
begin
  declare v_max int unsigned default 83;-- number of registers that I have
  declare v_counter int unsigned default 0;
  declare a int default 0;
    start transaction;
    while v_counter < v_max do
       update db.tb_table set new_column= (@a := @a+1) where id> 0; 
       set v_counter=v_counter+1;
    end while;
 commit;
end #
call fill_column();
```

Thanks guys =)

Comment: note :  declare a int default 0; is NOT @a . you can also direct use: set new_column = v_counter - if set the default to 1